# saved Recorded Audio Using Audio intent cannot be played

Tags: android, android-intent, android-audiorecord

I am making an app that allows that user to record audio. I used Audio intent for this. What I am trying to do is to record audio, set its name, and save it in a folder. In my code, the audio was saved and named properly but when I try to play it, it says that "Sorry, it cannot be played." I don't know where I go a mistake. Help me please, I will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
.....
private void dispatchTakeAudioIntent(int actionCode) 
{
    Intent takeAudioIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

    File a = null;
    try {
            a = setUpAudioFile();
            mCurrentAudioPath = a.getAbsolutePath();
            takeAudioIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(a));
        } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                a = null;
                mCurrentVideoPath = null;
            }
    startActivityForResult(takeAudioIntent, ACTION_TAKE_AUDIO);


}

 private File setUpAudioFile() throws IOException {

    File v = createAudioFile();
    mCurrentVideoPath = v.getAbsolutePath();

    return v;
}

private File createAudioFile() throws IOException 
{
    // Create an audio file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String audioFileName = AUDIO_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File audioF = File.createTempFile(audioFileName, AUDIO_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return audioF;
}

private void galleryAddAudio() 
{
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(mCurrentAudioPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO: 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }

        break;

    }
    case ACTION_TAKE_AUDIO: 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //audioFileUri = data.getData();
            handleAudio(data);
            //galleryAddVideo();
        }
        break;
    } 
    } // switch
}

private void handleAudio(Intent data) {

    audioFileUri = data.getData();
    if (mCurrentAudioPath != null) 
    {
        //audioFileUri = data.getData();
        galleryAddAudio();
        mCurrentAudioPath = null;
    }

}

........
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations regarding **RECORD_SOUND_ACTION** intent that it is not supported to specify a file path to save the audio recording. The application shall save the audio in default location. You cannot use **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** as extra because in document of [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) it is written under constant **EXTRA_OUTPUT** that it only use for image and video.

```
The name of the Intent-extra used to indicate a content resolver Uri to be used to store the requested image or video.
```

A solution to this cause is bit tricky. You can let the application save the audio to default but after you can cut, paste and rename your audio to your required location. I found two answers who claims that they found a way to cut paste.

[Solution A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305427/how-can-i-specify-the-output-files-folder-when-calling-record-sound-action)

[Solution B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043921/how-to-save-the-recorded-audio-files-in-another-folder-programmatically)

Accept this answer or +1 if you find it useful.