# How to save audio in sd-card based on spinner value

Tags: java, android, audio, android-spinner, audio-recording

I am creating application of recording audio and save it inside SD-card. So when user tap on record audio button a pop-up is coming which ask user to enter audio name. So with this pop-up i have added one spinner which basically loads data from database.

So what i want to do is whenever user select any value from spinner then with that particular name a new folder should automatically create and save that audio inside that folder.

Ex. say i have 5 value in spinner A, B, C, D, and E, so when user select A and press OK button then i want to create folder name Called **A** inside SD-card and that audio should store inside **A** Folder. same as with others if user select **B** then i want to create folder **B** inside SD-card and it should store that audio inside **B** folder.

```
spinnerListData.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Spinner Item selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER;
                String path = filepath + String.valueOf(Code.audioName) + ".mp4";
                recorder.setOutputFile(path);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

So this is basic code which saves audio inside AudioRecorder folder of SD-card. But i don't know how to achieve what i wanted to do. If anyone have any idea or sample code then please help me.

Comment: Go to this link: May be helps you.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043921/how-to-save-the-recorded-audio-files-in-another-folder-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043921/how-to-save-the-recorded-audio-files-in-another-folder-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the selected item from spinner and put it with the file path. Suppose you have array passed to spinner `String [] spinnerItem;`, you can get the clicked item and create folder as below:

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + spinnerItem[position];
            String path = filepath + String.valueOf(Code.audioName) + ".mp4";
            recorder.setOutputFile(path);
```